# Pandas numpy.lookfor equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Numpy has great help function that allows me to search through the numpy documentation from terminal.

Is there something similar to `numpy.lookfor` function that works for pandas library?
I know that `numpy.info` works with pandas functions and methods but I have to know the name of the method beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no such thing for Pandas library as of today. However useful tip I found out is that you can press tab while typing pandas method in Jupyter Notebook, so it will suggest some possible methods. 
Also by pressing shift and tab you can get information about the method within jupyter notebook. Pressing shift and 4 times tab will conveniently open a simple window that contains all the information about specific method.
Not exactly as `numpy.lookfor` but stil useful.